# Setting saturday and sunday not clickable in ionic calendar app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have seen a tutorial on internet : 
"https://devdactic.com/ionic-calendar-app/" on how to do an event calendar in ionic , I have done it but I have an issue, if I want  to make Saturday and Sunday for example unlikable(not being able to set events on all Saturday and Sundays),

my calendar html file:

```
         <ion-header>

        <ion-navbar color="BlueNew">
       <ion-title>
        Home
        </ion-title>

         <ion-buttons start>
         <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addEvent()">
         <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        </ion-buttons>

        </ion-navbar>

        </ion-header>
         <ion-content>
       <p style="text-align:center;">{{ viewTitle }}</p>
       <ion-navbar color="white">

        <ion-buttons end>

        <button ion-button [disabled]="isToday" (click)="today  ()">Today</button>
        <button ion-button (click)="changeMode('day')">D</button>
        <button ion-button (click)="changeMode('week')">W</button>
        <button ion-button (click)="changeMode('month')">M</button>



        </ion-buttons>
        </ion-navbar>

            <calendar [eventSource]="eventSource"
            [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"
            [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
           (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
           (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
           (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)"
           step="30"
         startHour="9"
         endHour="19"
         allDayLabel=""
         class="calendar">
     </calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find all the Sunday and Saturday in a month and then pass those date in marked disable

here is working link check home.ts file

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-calendar-scheduler-tuuwp3

```
    <calendar ... [markDisabled]="markDisabled"></calendar>

    markDisabled = (date: Date) => {

        return  (date.getDay()==6 || date.getDay()==0);
    };
```

Comment: what does date.getDay()==6 or = 0 mean? and if I want for example to let a doctor for example choose a day between 4 pm to 7pm as disabled to not be able to insert event between these times? thank you

Comment: and how to assign startHour a variable to be able to set it from typescript??

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy 6 means saturday and sunday means 0  and about time you have to convert  in 24 hr format on event click you can check that the time is already in database or not from there you can check the event between these time